# Is there any dataset for party primaries adoption?

Tags: parties, primaries, data-sources

Is there any data set available with information about parties around the world that have adopted primary elections?

Comment: This may be a better question for [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JJJ We have a [meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/is-asking-for-a-data-source-a-valid-question) discussion on this.